# How to convert resultset to nested unordered list and hide sublist items with a value of 0?

Tags: php, loops, conditional-statements, html-lists, resultset

I am trying to display the below table value in list and sub-list.

[image: [Database table]

and here is my for loop to display

```
$sql ="SELECT *FROM objectives"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$categories = array();

foreach ($result as $result) {
    $category = $result['content'];
    $categories[$category][] = $result['sub_content'];
}
?>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($categories as $category => $subcategories): ?>
  <li>
    <?php echo $category; ?>
    <ul>
<?php foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory):?>
      <li><?php echo $subcategory; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
  </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

[image: output]

The data is displayed in list and with sub list. I don't want to display the `0` value in the sub-list.

Everything is fine except the display of `0` in sub-list. Please advise.

Comment: Please offer text-based details in your question.  Images cannot be copy-pasted by volunteers who want to design and test their solutions. Writing `foreach($result as $result){` is not advisable.  Using 2 separate loops is not necessary.

Comment: What is your EXACT expected result?  If the only sub-item is `0` do you want to display the parent? or not?

Comment: Yes sure i will used text instead image in future. the parent needs to be displayed even if its child is 0 and i have achieved it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply implementing `echo ($subcategory != '0')? '<li>'.$test.'</li>' : '';` will result in needless markup in the dom.  Specifically, you will have empty `<ul></ul>` tags as nested lists where only a single row containing `$subcategory` is `0`.  ([Demonstration](https://3v4l.org/Z58Xo))  These extra bits of markup may cause funky side-effects when css/styling is applied.

Further refinements are advisable as a matter of best practice:

- When querying the database, only `SELECT` the columns that you specifically require for your task.
- Add stability to your process by using an `ORDER BY` clause that will group the rows by `content` and possibly sort `sub_content`
- Never use more loops than necessary.  This task can be (and therefore, theoretically, should be) performed in a single loop.

Recommended Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/uICaV))

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT content, sub_content FROM objectives");
$category = null;
$output = '';
foreach ($result as $row) {
    if ($category !== $row['content']) {             // new parent
        if ($category !== null) {                    // not first iteration
            $output .= "<li>$category";              // print parent
            if ($sublist) {
                $output .= "<ul>$sublist</ul>";      // print all children
            }
            $output .= "</li>";
        }
        $category = $row['content'];                 // overwrite $category
        $sublist = '';                               // reset sublist
    }
    if ($row['sub_content'] !== '0'){                // filter row
        $sublist .= "<li>{$row['sub_content']}</li>";
    }
}
if ($result) {                                       // in case the resultset is empty
    echo "<ul>";
        echo $output;                                // print stored markup
        echo "<li>$category";                        // print last parent
        if ($sublist) {
            echo "<ul>$sublist</ul>";                // print all children from last parent
        }
        echo  "</li>";
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Source Code Output:

```
<ul>
    <li>Demonstrate where to find the following documentation:
        <ul>
            <li>Operating and Safety Strategy</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Explain the different turbine main operating states:
        <ul>
            <li>Power Production</li>
            <li>Idle</li>
            <li>Stop</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Explain how to recognise the current operating mode on the display of the operating panel</li>
    <li>Explain the subsystem operating modes:
        <ul>
            <li>Stop</li>
            <li>Manual</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Explain the difference between local and remote point of operation</li>
    <li>Explain that only one point of operation can be active at a time</li>
</ul>
```

Rendered Output: (courtesy of phptester.net)

[image]

Comment: You are welcome.  It is important to me that I provide comprehensive / educational support to you AND future researchers.

Answer (score 2):

try this if you just don't want to display 0

```
<?php echo ($subcategory != '0')? '<li>'.$test.'</li>' : ''; ?>
```

and if you don't want to store in array then put this if condition

```
foreach ($result as $result) {
    $category = $result['content'];
    if($result['sub_content'] != '0'){
       $categories[$category][] = $result['sub_content'];
    }
}
```